# How to determine whether IIS7 is installed under a local machine

Tags: c#, .net, iis

How can I check that IIS7 is installed under OS ?

I am in .net 4.0

Thanks .

Comment: Programatically, that is? Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435050/how-to-determine-installed-iis-version)

Comment: There are a number of approaches suggested at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446390/how-to-detect-iis-version-using-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mmmmm looks like you need to search google

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18301/Using-Managed-Code-to-Detect-if-IIS-is-Installed-a

http://blogs.iis.net/chrisad/archive/2006/09/01/Detecting-if-IIS-is-installed_2E002E002E00_.aspx

http://geekswithblogs.net/sdorman/archive/2007/03/01/107732.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following

```
string w3wp = Path.Combine(
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), "inetsrv\w3wp.exe");
FileVersionInfo versionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(w3wp);
Console.WriteLine(versionInfo.FileMajorPart);
```

You could also check Windows Registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W3SVC\Parameters for the Major Version.

Answer (score -2):

You can go to Start --> Run and type inetmgr and enter which would open up your IIS and you can check the version there.