# Finding Version of IIS using powershell

Tags: iis, powershell

I wish to find the version of IIS using a powershell (or WMI) query.

The following is the query which I have used.

```
Get-WmiObject -namespace "root\microsoftiisv2" -query "select MajorIIsVersionNumber from IISWebInfo"
```

I tested this query using powershell console in a 'Windows 8' PC with 'IIS 8'. But the result is 7 , where the expected version Number is 8.

Can someone help me to solve this issue?.

Comment: The answers to this question might help: ["How to determine installed IIS version"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435050/how-to-determine-installed-iis-version)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can try:

```
get-itemproperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\  | select setupstring,versionstring
```

Comment: This will give correct answer, But It would be great if there is a WMI or Powershell query for the same.

Comment: @user1805353 I'm sorry but I'm not aware for other methods, maybe the powershell 'webadministration' module can help.

Comment: This is not reliable because it can return values on servers that do not have IIS installed. Whether or not they once had IIS on, I can't confirm just yet, but I can definitely confirm IIS is not running / installed on some machines that have this reg key.

Comment: @Rob, @ CB. , Besides that, is there an **official source** from Microsoft that states `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\VersionString` is the way to get the version? Otherwise, such reverse engineering might seriously break in the future when the keys/values are changed...

Comment: I'm looking for servers without IIS installed.  So before I get-itemproperty I check if the item exist first. gci HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft | ?{$_.Name -match 'InetStp'}

Answer (score 8):

Even though the thread is little old,this is the link I landed first. So letting you know what I found.

The below command helped me find the IIS version correctly on IIS 8.5 (Windows 2012 R2) and 7.5 Windows 7 SP1.

***[System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo("$env:SystemRoot\system32\inetsrv\InetMgr.exe").ProductVersion***

**Reference:**

https://forums.iis.net/p/1171695/1984536.aspx : Answer from f00_beard

Answer (score 3):

If you want the decimal value for order comparison.

```
$iisInfo = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\
$version = [decimal]"$($iisInfo.MajorVersion).$($iisInfo.MinorVersion)"
```

Comment: Honestly, I think this should use the `[version]` type instead of decimal. If there was a version 10.10 it would be less than version 10.2 if a decimal type was used.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little ScriptBlock function that I created based on the answer from @C.B. to get the IIS Version from a remote computer.

```
$pwd = convertto-securestring "yourstrongpasswordhere" -asplaintext -force
$cred=new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "machinenamehere\adminusernamehere",$pwd

$iisversion= Invoke-Command -ComputerName $machineName -ScriptBlock { 

    $(get-itemproperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\).setupstring

} -Credential $cred

Write-Host iisversion = $iisversion
If($iisversion -like '*IIS 6*'){
    Write-Host This server uses IIS6
}

If($iisversion -like '*IIS 7*'){
    Write-Host This server uses IIS7
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For purely the version, I prefer checking the info on the w3wp executable.
[Per the "how-to" article from MSFT](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/how-to-obtain-versions-of-7875ac84):

```
    If(Test-Path $w3wpPath) { 
        $productProperty = Get-ItemProperty -Path $w3wpPath 
        Write-Host $productProperty.VersionInfo.ProductVersion 
    } 
    Else { 
        Write-Host "Not find IIS." 
    }
```